# Read one2many field in inherited model

Tags: python, odoo-13

In odoo v13, the `crm.lead` model is inherited and modified by the `sale_crm` module.

In the `sale_crm` module, the model `crm.lead` is inherited and a `one2many` field is added, `order_ids`. This is an array of sales orders associated with the `lead`.

I am trying to inherit the `crm.lead` model, and create a new field that is computed using the `order_ids` field.

1. I added `sale_crm` in the manifest dependencies
2. I inherit the `crm.lead` model and attempt to concat the names of all the associated SOs:

   ```
   class Co7Lead(models.Model):
    _inherit = "crm.lead"

    so_list = fields.Text(
        compute='_get_sos_text',
        string="Text list of associated SOs",
        help="A comma separated list of SOs associated with this lead")

    def _get_sos_text(self):
        txt = ""

        for order in super(Co7Lead, self).order_ids:
            txt += order.name + ""

        return txt
   ```

Unfortunately, this causes a stack overflow (haha!)

I believe I need to use `.browse` on the `order_ids` field but I'm not able to find any examples on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [compute](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/developer/reference/addons/orm.html#computed-fields) method must assign the computed value to the field. If it uses the values of other fields (`order_ids.name`), it should specify those fields using [depends()](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/developer/reference/addons/orm.html#odoo.api.depends).

You don't need to use `super` here, `self` is a record set, so loop over it to access the value of `order_ids` for each record.

***Example:***

```py
@api.depends('order_ids.name')
def _get_sos_text(self):
    for lead in self:
         lead.so_list = "\n".join(order.name for order in lead.order_ids)
```